# Router not receiving internet connection from modem

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, internet, modem

My ISP supplied me with an Arris TM822G/CT modem and a NetgearWNR1000v2 router.

I can plug my computer directly into the modem and I get internet connection.

I can plug the modem and my computer into two different LAN ports and get internet connection.

When I plug in the modem to WAN, where it should go, and my computer into LAN, I get no internet connection.

Plugging my computer into the router via LAN with nothing else connected to the router does not allow me to change the router settings.

Comment: A more detailed problem description than just "I get no internet connection" would be helpful. Do you get assigned an IP address? Can you reach the router? Can you reach the modem?

Answer (score 0):

Your netgear appears to not be leasing an IP from the modem, you need to login to it and configure its WAN connection through the setup wizard.